# Angular SSR with Firebase Cloud function always return 404 when user direct access by entering URL

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I followed this link to create an Angular SSR with Firebase cloud function [LINK](https://bapittu.medium.com/angular-9-universal-ssr-with-firebase-and-deployment-in-cloud-function-54867020a656)

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "myproject",
      "public": "dist/myproject/browser",
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*"
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "*.[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f].+(css|js)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "ssr" <-- My cloud function name
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

**functions/index.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const regionalFunctions = functions.region('asia-east2');
const universal = require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/myproject/server/main`).app();

export const ssr = regionalFunctions.https.onRequest(universal);
```

By running the `firebase serve` command, to test in my local machine

```
i  hosting[myproject]: Serving hosting files from: dist/smyproject/browser
✔  hosting[myproject]: Local server: http://localhost:5000
✔  functions[asia-east2-ssr]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/myproject/asia-east2/ssr).
```

In my local machine, it works fine when I enter `http://localhost:5000` or anything like `http://localhost:5000/some/path/in-my-angular-routing` it will be redirected to my default page

But when I use `ng deploy` command and test on production, if I enter `https://myproject-id.web.app`or anything like `https://myproject-id.web.app/some/path/in-my-angular-routing`, it will always return 404.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try to `firebase serve` it on a different port. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I have updated my post. It will not work only in production.